# Create a random CLLocationCoordinate in a certain area

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, dictionary

I've got an `MKMapRect`.

How do I create a random `CLLocationCoordinate` inside there?

I know there is `arc4random()`, but how can I use it for GPS Coordinates?

Comment: what is that MKMapRect value you are using?
Please tell me i also have the same problem how you solved this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX      0x100000000
... 

//val is a double between 0 and 1
double xOffset = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);
double yOffset = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);
MKMapPoint randomPoint;

randomPoint.x = maprect.origin.x + xOffset*maprect.size.width;
randomPoint.y = maprect.origin.y + yOffset*maprect.size.height;

CLLocationCoordinate2D randomCoordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(randomPoint);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working nicely. Can you explain what `0x100000000` does?

Comment: This is just the max value arc4random can generate (in hex format). If you divide the result generated by arc4random by this value, you get a floating point number between 0 and 1

Comment: As written, this will only generate points along a diagonal line in the map rect, since you're using the same random value for each axis. (i.e. you want to use a different `val` to make randomPoint.y)

Comment: @JesseRusak Thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the MapRect, you could got `MKMapPoint origin` and `MKMapSize size`, then the random CLLocationCoordinate should be `{origin.x + [0 ~ size.width], origin.y + [0 ~ size.height]}`

```
typedef struct {
       MKMapPoint origin;
       MKMapSize size;
    } MKMapRect;
```

the code like this:

```
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX      0x100000000
- (double)createRandomsizeValueFloat:(double)fromFloat toFloat:(double)toFloat
{
    if (toFloat < fromFloat) {
        return toFloat;
    } else if (toFloat == fromFloat) {
        return fromFloat;
    }
    return ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX) * (toFloat - fromFloat) + fromFloat;
}

//CLLocationDegrees lat = mapRect.origin.x + [self createRandomsizeValueFloat:0 toFloat:mapRect.size.width];
//CLLocationDegrees lng = mapRect.origin.y + [self createRandomsizeValueFloat:0 toFloat:mapRect.size.height];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `latitude` and `longitude` properties of your `CLLocationCoordinate` instance.

Take care about ranges : -90 < latitude < 90, -180 < longitude < 180.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't really help. He/She is looking to keep that location within a certain area.